# SAS ODS Excel to produce a excel sheet with three tables side by side

Tags: sas, ods

I am trying to prepare a report in Excel using ODS Excel in SAS. The report contains two sheets with three tables place side by side.  I used Panelcol option but it is not available in ODS Excel. Also, the Start_at= option does not seem to be working?

Is there anyway it can be done in ODS Excel? Please let me know.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thank you,
Shankar

Comment: Can you provide some example code showing what you're trying that's not working?  Maybe code that works in ODS PDF or TAGSETS.EXCELXP if that's what you're more familiar with?  Use SASHELP.CLASS.

Comment: Also, you'll want to include your SAS version including maintenance release (SAS 9.4 TS1M4 is mine, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Shankar:

The ODS EXCEL docs for 9.4 state the start_at= options can not be changed mid-sheet. [Link](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odsug/69832/HTML/default/p09n5pw9ol0897n1qe04zeur27rv.htm#p0258wnlz15ubrn1vqfalp6l4hjz)

> (START_AT='string') specifies a starting cell for the report. The
>   default is to start at column 1 and row 1. Default    1,1 Tip This option
>   cannot be changed in the middle of a sheet. Example    ods excel
>   options(start_at="2,2");

So this example **does not** work as you expect.  The first start_at is honored, and subsequent output on the same page is stacked while still honoring the first start at column.

```
ods _all_ close;    
ods excel file='%temp%\3-tables-in-first-tab-sample.xlsx'
  options (sheet_interval='none')
;

ods excel options (start_at="2,2");

* top of output is upper left corner;
proc print noobs data=sashelp.class(keep=name age);run;

* top of output is to the right and down three rows from the first output;
ods excel options (start_at="5,5");

proc print noobs data=sashelp.class(keep=name weight height);run;

ods excel options (start_at="1,9");
proc print noobs data=sashelp.class(keep=name sex);run;

ods excel close;
```

One way to put multiple tables together is to create a faux table that appends data in a sidewise manner.

Example:

```
%macro RHS_append (out=, data=);
  %if not %sysfunc(exist(&out)) %then %do;
    data &out; set &data; run;
    %return;
  %end;

  %local nout names labels;

  proc contents noprint data=&out out=outvar(keep=name varnum label);
  proc contents noprint data=&data out=datavar(keep=name varnum label);
  proc sql noprint; select count(*) into :nout trimmed from outvar;
  select 
    cats(name,'=v',&nout+varnum+1) 
  , case 
      when label='' 
      then cats('v',&nout+varnum+1,'=',quote(trim(name)))
      else ''
    end
  into
    :names separated by ' '
  , :labels separated by ' '
  from datavar order by varnum
  ;
  create table gap (v%eval(&nout+1) char(1) label='a0'x);
  quit;

  data &out;
    merge &out gap &data(rename=(&names)); %* rare use of merge without by;
    label &labels;
  run;

%mend;

options mprint;

proc delete data=foo;
run;
%RHS_append (out=foo, data=sashelp.class);
%RHS_append (out=foo, data=sashelp.gas);
%RHS_append (out=foo, data=sashelp.cars);

ods excel file='%temp%\3-tables-in-first-tab-sample.xlsx';

proc print label data=foo;
run;

ods excel close;
```